# More efficient way to do binary search in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, binary-search

I am doing a question on Binary Search using C++, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to implement it.

My code is as follows:

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
    if (r >= l) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
 
        if (arr[mid] == x) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] > x) {
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: [std::lower_bound/upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: Binary search does not require recursion. Getting rid of recursion is, unquestionably, more "efficient" (assuming that the compiler isn't smart enough to do it for you).

Comment: @Mat: it this assumed to be "more efficient" ?

Comment: In developer time/debugging: yes, @YvesDaoust

Comment: What is efficient? Always a thorny question.

Comment: My definition of `efficient` here is takes less time  to run

Comment: well its always good to have more than one opinion 

Comment: The answer you accepted is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a proponent of binary search *without* comparison for equality, so that every reduction step takes a single comparison (you perform a single comparison for equality in the end, when the interval has shrunk).

The idea of comparison for equality is that you can terminate the search earlier when the key is found. If the key is found at depth d, this takes 2d comparisons. The average number of comparisons is twice the average depth of the tree, and is 2 Log2(N) - 1 for a perfect tree (early termination only spares one comparison).

This is to be compared to Log2(N) without equality test. Not counting that when the key is not found, the full depth of the tree is always traversed ! Testing for equality seems a false good idea.

Answer (score -2):

Binary Search is a very efficient method for searching any particular value in our arrays.. especially in very long-sized arrays, where the conventional linear search method can consume huge compilation time. Talking about time complexities => linear search O(n) whereas Binary Search have time complexity: O(log2n) {log n with base 2}

so there are no other optimizations needed in is this binary search code but yeah.. instead of binary search you can learn about **TERNARY SEARCH** which is not faster than Binary Search but good for learning new things...
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search/

**Ternary Search is just like Binary Search, but in this, the array is divided into 3 parts then we do the comparison. Also the time complexity of Ternary Searcg is O(log3n) :log n with base 3**

Comment: Ternary search is used to find the maximum (or the minimum) of an unimodal function. Using ternary search to find a value in a sorted array is not a good idea -- binary search is better.

Comment: This is a false good idea, ternary search is slower. Because you indeed need Log3 reduction steps instead of Log2, but every step takes 1 or 2 comparisons instead of 1, say 1.5 on average. [I am assuming an algorithm without comparison for equality.] Then, 1.5/Ln(3) > 1. By the way, following this logic, K-ary search would be even better, with a LogK performance, and K as large as you want.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why the big-O notation is appropriate: you claim that O(Log3(N)) is better than O(Log2(N)). But in big-O notation, both are identical and just written O(Log(N)): this is quite inconclusive. And when you check it, the hidden asymptotic constant favors binary search.